# unable to get node key name of nested array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to display nested array, and it prints whole array but unable to print node element like in our example [destinations],[QUOTATIONS].
i want to print array with this node elements.

actually i am generating tree view using this nested element that why i need to display node element also.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 148
    [status] => I
    [consname] => juned  ansari
    [consusername] => junedconsultant
    [agency_name] => mayur
    [agency_username] => MayurMaroliya
    [destinations] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 260
                    [from_date] => 2016-11-24
                    [to_date] => 2016-11-29
                    [country_id] => IN
                    [QUOTATIONS] => Array
                        (
                              [id] => 260
                              [name] => ABC  
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

here is my recursion code.

```
<?php
function traverseArray($array)
{
    // Loops through each element. If element again is array, function is recalled. If not, result is echoed.
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            traverseArray($value);
        } else {
            if (gettype($value) == 'object') {
                echo "<ul>";
                traverseArray($value);
            } else {
                echo '<li><a href="#">' . $key . " : " . $value . '</a>';
            }
        }
    }
}
traverseArray($transition_data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print node element in `if` block of you `array checking`. like:

```
if (is_array($value)) {
            echo $key;//this will print the nodes(destinations,QUOTATIONS) .you cal add ul here
            traverseArray($value);
        }
```